# Extract the paired samples from a listing of all samples

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am comparing genomic profiles of identical samples and I need to extract the paired samples from a listing of all samples, so as an illustration how can I adapt  "How can I get  list of duplicates...." to this problem of keeping only lists that have duplicated samples.

`{{sample1,2},{sample1,3},{sample2,3},{sample3,4},{sample3,6}}`

=>

`{{sample1,2},{sample1,3},{sample3,4},{sample3,6}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine, the following

```
F[list_] := Flatten[Select[Gather[list, First[#1] == First[#2] &], Length[#] > 1 &], 1]
```

is faster than

```
G[list_] := Flatten[Cases[GroupBy[list, First], {_, __}], 1]
```

although I am not entirely sure why:  I suspect it has to do with pattern matching being slower.  When the number of unpaired samples is large, the evaluation time discrepancy increases.

Comment: Kuba's use of `GroupBy` was unnecessary and counterproductive.  I corrected his answer to use `GatherBy` instead and it is now much faster.

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {{sample1, 2}, {sample1, 3}, {sample2, 3}, {sample3, 
   4}, {sample3, 6}}
```

```
Flatten[Cases[GatherBy[list, First], {_, __}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{sample1, 2}, {sample1, 3}, {sample3, 4}, {sample3, 6}}
> ```

So for

```
list = {{sample1, 1}, {sample2, 1}}
```

we will get

> ```
> {}
> ```

as there are no duplicates in `sample*`.

Comment: Much more elegant than what I had in the mean time `Select[list, Count[Flatten@list, First@#] > 1 &]`

Comment: @Feyre A matter of preference I suppose ;)

Comment: As of 10.0, there's `Catenate` for `Flatten[..., 1]`.

Comment: @MartinEnder and `Join @@` is sometimes faster than either, e.g. if the input list is a packed array in this case, so it is *still* often my first choice.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I used `GroupBy`, I could have bet it wasn't the case. Thanks for correction of that typo :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html) for this task.

```
data = {{sample1, 2}, {sample1, 3}, {sample2, 3}, {sample3, 4}, {sample3, 6}};
DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, Last]
```

> `{{sample1, 2}, {sample1, 3}, {sample3, 4}, {sample3, 6}}`

Comment: I think OP picked unfortunate example because the point is to keep entries which appear more than once base on the first element. So `{{sample1,1},{sample2,1}}` shoul be left empty while your method will give `{{sample1,1}}`

Comment: @Kuba. I think you're right.